# How to multiply all the elements in the pandas dataframe with int16 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, types, numpy-ndarray

The pandas dataframe has seven columns with 100 rows.It is converted into numpy nd array using `arr = df.to_numpy()`.Now, I have to multiply each element with 2^15 to convert each value into int16 equivalent.The ndarray is given here with only 9 rows.

```
dtype: object
[[ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.063  0.125  0.187  0.249  0.309  0.368  0.426]
 [ 0.125  0.249  0.368  0.482  0.588  0.685  0.771]
 [ 0.187  0.368  0.536  0.685  0.809  0.905  0.969]
 [ 0.249  0.482  0.685  0.844  0.951  0.998  0.982]
 [ 0.309  0.588  0.809  0.951  1.     0.951  0.809]
 [ 0.368  0.685  0.905  0.998  0.951  0.771  0.482]
 [ 0.426  0.771  0.969  0.982  0.809  0.482  0.063]
```

after mulitplying , the float values must be convert into the values multiplied with2^15.
The sample output is [image: column 1 changed values]

Comment: What did you tried? It seems just a multiplication is needed and possibly a conversion with `astype`.

Comment: Thanks @Jérôme Richard. I converted and posted the answer. But I have a doubt on column length. Does the pandas Data Frame allows us to add column of different length.?

Comment: AFAIK, no, a dataframe is a bit like a 2D numpy array except columns can be of different types. You can fill the remaining values with NaN (which is not great) or simply store the result in a list of array instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['1Hz','2Hz', '3Hz', '4Hz', '5Hz', '6Hz', '7Hz'])
df['1Hz']=(2**15) *pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(1))
df['2Hz']=(2**15) *pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(2))
df['3Hz']=(2**15) *pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(3))
df['4Hz']=(2**15) *pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(4))
df['5Hz']=(2**15) *pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(5))
df['6Hz']=(2**15) *pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(6))
df['7Hz']=(2**15) *pd.Series(get_values_for_frequency(7))
df = df.round(decimals = 3)
df = df.astype(np.int16)
```

Comment: Be careful about overflows: `np.int16(np.float32(1)*(2**15))` gives a negative number. You could use `np.uint16` or multiply by `2**15-1`. Clamping the output before the cast can be important too to avoid 1.0000001 being converted to a bad value. Such issue creates some unexpected "crackling" in audio output that are hard to debug.